# Make Eclipse forget "remember my decision" for open debug perspective

Tags: eclipse

When launching an app in debug mode it asked me if I wanted to open debug perspective. I checked remember my decision but must have accidentally clicked 'Yes' instead of 'No'. How can I undo this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the 'Preferences' and go to the 'Run/Debug > Perspectives' page to see the settings for the perspectives used by debug.

You probably want the 'Open the associated perspective when launching' option set to Prompt or Never.